# I improved an old, downvoted, already answered question. How can I attract potential upvoters?

Tags: discussion, quality-improvement

In my earlier days of Stack Overflow I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433846/can-an-sql-injection-be-made-with-a-single-word-in-a-select-statement). My goal was to learn more about SQL injection, and the reasoning behind the established SQL best practices.

Due to a lack of question writing experience on my part, the question did not reflect my goal clearly, and people thought I was actively trying to avoid good practices. Thus downvotes followed.

After a while someone *did* post a really good answer, and I accepted it. The answer even got a couple of upvotes.

Fast forward 9 months. I have learned much, and I'm actively trying to improve the quality of everything I've done on the site. I edited the question to make my intent more obvious. The question has been improved. One could even say that the some of the existing downvotes have lost their validity.

How does one get this kind of improvement recognized and upvoted?

The question already has an accepted answer, so putting a bounty on it does not make a lot of sense. Flagging it also seems a little strange, since I'm not sure what a moderator is supposed to do in this situation.

Most of the time, I simply delete my old, downvoted questions, but I think the answer is good, and people should be able to see it.

Comment: When you edited it it probably got a bit more exposure (as it does now that you explicitly posted it on meta). In the end, I'd say don't worry about little things like this. You fixed the ambiguities and I believe that that's truly what matters. If someone finds it useful in the future he is much more likely to upvote as helpful, let time work its magic.

Comment: Productive use of SO is fishing for good answers, not fishing for votes.  You got one, done.  If your question didn't get many views in the past 9 months then it isn't hitting the Google sweet-spot.  With 58 views it isn't, no where in sight when you query "php sql injection".  Which is not that surprising, most programmers will look for the bigger picture and won't focus on a corner-case.

Comment: @HansPassant, I understand your point. My only concern is that there might be many cases where the votes do not represent the quality of questions, due to edits made at a later stage. I'm pretty sure the fact that my question has been downvoted also damages its search engine ranking. I was hoping that there was a specific way to deal with this kind of situation on SO.

Comment: IMO, *"How can this be exploited by attackers?"* is an open ended question that is way too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TinyGiant I edited it to make the question more specific. Is it still too broad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question picked up all the votes (3 down/1 up) on the first day of posting. Analyzing the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28433846/timeline) reveals that.

By editing your question you obviously did bring it to attention of some voters who decided to reward the *answers* with an up vote.

You can't delete the question because it has up voted answers. You'll have to live with the burden of a down voted question on your profile. Except from some extra attention you get here there is not much else you can do.

Don't expect a massive turn around in the next 6 to 8 weeks, specially as it only got viewed by 58 visitors in 9 months. So on the positive side: 54 decided not to down vote ;)

Comment: 54 people saw the OK me instead of the bad me :-)

Comment: @CoertGrobbelaar: And actually you got 7 rep and lost 6 rep from that question, so `7 - 6 == 1`, don't need sad :)

Comment: Yay! The question has reached 0